# gcm-server.jar bad major version at offset=6

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with gcm-server.jar. 
Until yesterday everything worked fine, now when I deploy my war file to server I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (com/google/android/gcm/server/InvalidRequestException) bad major version at offset=6
```

When I open gcm-server.jar there is comment:

```
Compiled from InvalidRequestException.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
```

I'm using eclipse running java5. 
What I need to do have it working with java5?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled necessary classes from gcm-server with jdk 5.0 and generated new gcm-server.jar. Now everything is working fine.